# idiomatic way to create a bean with parameter from command line?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

for example, in my spring application, I need several DBWorker Beans:

```
    @Component
    @Scope("prototype")
    class DBWorker {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate templ;

    @Autowired
    SomeOtherDependency dep;


    public void init() {
        // use jdbcTemplate to pull some 
        // set up info from DB

   }

   public void run() {
    // pull maxNumberOfRows and print out
   }


    private int maxNumberOfRowsToPull;

    public void setMaxNumberOfRowsToPull() { .... }

    }
```

so basically I have a class DBWorker , which needs a bunch of dependencies, such as a jdbctemplate. it's convenient to let Spring inject these dependencies, so I mark these dependencies as @Autowired.  in my application, I need 3 DBWorkers at different places, all having the same dependencies for jdbcTemplate and SomeOtherDependency. but each of them has a different maxNumberOfRowsToPull, which are all set by command line args.

the logical steps I need to perform on the DBWorker's are:
instantiate 3 workers
call init() on each worker
call run() on each worker

because the maxNumberOfRowsToPull comes from command line (is not fixed), I can't put it in spring config.xml or use @Value annotation, even though I could use ${system.property.name} in config , this would be different for 3 workers, and I would have to set system property 3 times to come indirectly to setMaxNumberOfRowsToPull(), which is ugly. 
so I have to call the setMaxNumberOfRowsToPull() directly. then before I call this, the "state" of the worker is not complete, so I can't call init() until after I call setMaxNumberOfRowsToPull() explicitly, so I can't put the init() logic in constructor, and have to call the init() explicitly too.  on the other hand, I want to autowire the dependencies, so I have to create the worker through spring (otherwise the dependencies won't be injected). so overall the best code I have now is:

```
DBWorker worker1 = (DBWorker) context.getBean(DBWorker.class);
// now the dependencies are already injected
worker1.setMaxNumberOfRowsToPull(args[0]);
worker1.setSomeOtherProperty(args[1]);
worker1.init();
worker1.run();

// then similar sequence for worker2 etc.
```

the ugly part is , if I have more properties from command line to set, I would have more calls like setMaxNumberOfRowsToPull(), and most of the workers share the same params, only a few need an explicit change. so I  set @Value for those properties to system property, and let Spring handle that. so every worker bean comes out from Spring with some "default" property setting, given by command line, and I will have to explicitly call property setting on a few to change the default values. this sounds a bit fishy since a few beans after creation are in the "wrong" state. I would rather have every bean to be correct when they are created, conceptually.

also I have to call this init() manually, because I have to wait for the manual call on property setting. supposedly the init() should be part of spring bean initialization() and i should not need to do this mechanical step for every dbworker.

Ideally I would like something cleaner like

```
DBWorker worker1 = context.getBean(DBWorker.class, args[0], args[1]);
// here the init() has been run inside constructor or in bean initialization()
worker1.run();
// then repeat above for worker2, worker3 ...
```

I would like to know what is the idiomatic and clean way to organize code for scenarios like this.
thanks!

Comment: You might consider using JavaConfig to instantiate and configure the beans, injecting values into the configuration class.

Comment: chrylis: thanks. javaconfig does seem the way to go, since it gives more flexibility. but how would a @Bean in JavaConfig access command line args ?  so far the only way I see that can pass a value down the chain is system properties, but if we go that way , essentially on the application you would end up calling similar steps (though saving us the init() call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put the variables on init?

```
 public void init(String numberOfRowsToPull, String otherProp) {
        // use jdbcTemplate to pull some 
        // set up info from DB
        this.numberOfRowsToPull = numberOfRowsToPull;
        this.otherProp = otherProp;
   }
```

In the main:

```
DBWorker worker1 = context.getBean(DBWorker.class);
worker1.init(args[0], args[1]);
worket1.run();
```

This is the standart and i met this in many places,It acts the same as constructor in case you want to change the default value..

Hope that helps

EDIT:

`BeanFactory` has a `getBean(String name, Object... args)`

I didn't try but this should do the work for you..

```
getBean("dBWorker", args[0], args[1]);
```

Comment: init(args[0], args[1]) would work. I just have a little bit of reservation since those properties are standard getters and setters, and represent "properties" of the bean, while init() kind of implies "run some one-time operation".

Comment: I edited my answer and added something that i think will help you request.. This thing should work. Instead of applicationContext use BeanFactory

Comment: ahh!  thanks!   that's exactly what I want.  how come I never knew of the args form of getBean()....